# Set Column Width in C# (Interop.Excel)

Tags: c#, excel

I have a c# script which successfully opens a specified Excel workbook, delete the first row and save it down as a csv format.

I have an issue that the CSV saves down as a standard col width of 8.43 I would like to change the col width of col J as 17.00 before saving down the csv.

Can someone please advise how I set the Col width of col J to 17.

I am unable to use VBA / Macros due to the process.

I am using;

```
myWorkSheet.Columns["J:J"].ColumnWidth = 17.57;
```

This however leads to an object does not contain definition for 'ColumnWidth' screenshot attached. [image]

Full code below;

```
        public void DeleteRows(string OriginalFileName,String NewFileName)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application myApp;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook myWorkBook;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet myWorkSheet;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range;
        myApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        myWorkBook = myApp.Workbooks.Open(OriginalFileName, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        myWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)myWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        range = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)myWorkSheet.Application.Rows[1, Type.Missing];
        range.Select();
        range.Delete(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDirection.xlUp);
        //Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range ThisRange1 = myWorkSheet.get_Range("J:J",System.Type.Missing);
        myWorkSheet.Columns["J:J"].ColumnWidth = 17.57; //ERRORLINE
        myApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
        myWorkSheet.SaveAs(NewFileName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSVWindows, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, false, false, false, XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        myWorkBook.Close(false);
        myApp.Quit();
    }
```

Comment: why are you using a range if you want to set the column width ?

Comment: just add reference to excel interop , that's all

Comment: Be sure to update your VS version.  Office programming in C# is pretty brutal in any version less than VS2010.  And hard to get help with it, SO users just don't understand why you have such a problem.

Comment: I am using VS2015 so hoping this shouldn't be the issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you need to set a range for this :

```
 Using Excel=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
 Excel.Worksheet myWorkSheet = new Excel.Worksheet;

 myWorkSheet.Columns["J:J"].ColumnWidth = 17.57;

///Or set width to AutoFit

 myWorkSheet.Columns.AutoFit();
```

Comment: Thanks! I have changed my code to 'myWorkSheet.Columns["J:J"].ColumnWidth = 17.57;' however ColumnWidth has come up with an error. "Object" does not contain definition for ColumnWidth.

Comment: I have inserted 'sheet.Columns["J:J"].ColumnWidth = 17.57;' however sheet does not exist in the current context

Comment: and please mark the answer as answer if it solved your issue :)

Comment: just add reference to excel interop , that's all

Comment: Thanks - I've edited the orginal post. I tried "myWorkSheet.Columns["J:J"].ColumnWidth = 17.57;" However it came up with the ColumnWidth object error which is now seen in the orginal post.

Comment: I'll edit my entire answer , this is actually an one line fix, u made it too much complicated

Comment: take a look at the answer again

Comment: Thanks - I have updated the code to reflect yours however I am still getting the ColumnWidth error in the screenshot.  I have also updated the code.

Comment: [let's talk in the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168247/beginners-of-c)

Comment: Thanks for your help yesterday! I have marked this as the right answer as it is :) and answered the question! Just to note the issue I was having was a system issue my side not the code you provided. Hence why I was baffled why it wasn't working.